# Nested loop of same entity using AngularJS ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end in HTML table tag

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor, angularjs-directive

Lets assume that I have an entity called GrandPa which is passed to my razor view, its model is as below(ParentChiled). As u see Child property is the List of ParentChiled class, using that GrandPa entity has 2 inner Child list of ParentChiled type which I want to loop thru each child also and print there Name.

```
Class ParentChiled
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<ParentChiled> Child {get;set;} //list of current class
}
```

**here what I tried**
Since I want to loop thru all the way down to inner most Child property using ng-repeat-start and end, therefor below is how I tried to loop thru each of them and print them. first and second row which are dad and Son are printing ***but grandSon which is in 3rd row is not printing***

```
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="dad in GrandPa">
    <td>{{dad.Name}}
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="Son in dad.Child">
    <td>{{Son.Name}}
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end="grandSon in Son.Child">
    <td>{{grandSon.Name}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also tried below links from stackoverflow but they are different than my question and I tried to adopt them to my question but did not work

```
[Link1][1]
[Link2][2]
[Link3][3]
[Link4][4]
```

**Note:** I tried debuging using Batarang chrome extension for angularjs and actually `{{grandSon.Name}}` has data so problem most probably is with ng-repeat

**I'm pretty new to stackoverflow, I apologize in advance if my question is not formated in the way you expected and I request you masters to correct me.**

Your help and support are appreciated

Comment: @Brandon tnx alot dear Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, I got it working perfectly fine

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="dad in GrandPa">
    <td>{{dad.Name}}
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="Son in dad.Child">
    <td>{{Son.Name}}
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="grandSon in Son.Child">
    <td>{{grandSon.Name}}
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true">
</table>
```

Enjoye ...